# R Shiny DataTable How to prevent row selection/deselection in columns containing hyperlinks

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I am dealing with a datatable with clickable element. A column of the row contains a hyperlink. When the hyperlin is clicked I don't want the row click event to be fired or managed (to select / deselect).

What I have tried on R Shiny:

```
function preventDefault(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();

   return false;
}
```

The element in DataTable which contains link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="preventDefault(event)";>
```

But nothing happened.

The full source code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
  DT::dataTableOutput("DTExample")


)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dat <- head(iris)

  dat <- dat %>% mutate(clickme = '<a href="#" 
                     onclick="event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation(); alert(event); return false;";
                     >CLICKME</a>')

  output$DTExample<- renderDataTable({
    datatable(dat, escape = FALSE, class = 'cell-border stripe')
  }) 
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Good suggestion. A sample code has been attached.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem happened because the "highlight action" is bind to "mousedown", which is happen earlier than the "click" event. You can not prevent the event happened before, right?

One simple solution is to use `onmousedown` instead of `onclick`

```
dat <- dat %>% mutate(clickme = '<a href="#" 
                    onmousedown="event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation(); alert(event); return false;";
                    >CLICKME</a>')
```

BTW, you can use chrome F12 to check the event listener. You can remove some listener to see the difference and find which listener is for "highlight"
[image]

Also, I found this because when I click the link but not release, the highlight happened but the click not happened. Then I realize this could be the key and check the event listener using Chrome. I hope you can understand the way of debugging!

Comment: awesome, works perfectly. Just need to remove `alert(event);` so the link is opened, with no row selection of course, but no alert message

Comment: I found that `onmousedown='event.stopPropagation();'` was sufficient to stop event bubbling in this case.

Comment: yes, I just do the least modification to make it worked, because the key is the difference between `onmousedown` and `onclick`.